# Set cover such that every vertex appears in at most k sets

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n\}$ and sets $\mathcal(F)=\{f_1,f_2,\dots, f_m\}$.

Is there any hardness result or approximation algorithm to find a set cover with this extra condition.
For every vertex $x_i$ appears in the intersection of at most k sets.

Comment: Your question is answered on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/191/bounded-cardinality-bounded-frequency-set-cover-hardness-of-approximation.